# How to use aio_read(3) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, io

In Linux one is able to asynchronously read from a file by calling [aio_read(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/aio_read.3.html) from C. A [sigevent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sigevent.7.html) structure is one of the parameters and there are different options one can specify to be notified when the operation is complete. Let me summarize:

- **SIGEV_NONE** no notification.

  The status can be checked with aio_error(3). The operation is async, but completion must be busily awaited in some loop which is not what I want.
- **SIGEV_SIGNAL** a signal is raised to the process.

  In theory, this can be caught in Haskell by installing a signal handler via [System.Posix.Signals](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Signals.html#t:SignalInfo). There is a problem though: the API of `SignalInfo` doesn't include the crucial `si_value` that let's one communicate some specifics about the read request, like a `StaticPtr`. This is unfortunate.
- **SIGEV_THREAD** this would start a new thread, according to the documentation.

  I don't know how to represent this in Haskell. My best guess would be an `IO ()` action. I'm not sure how to write the accompanying native code.

---

How can I use `aio_read` or something of that sort in Haskell? I will probably not get around using FFI on this (or a library).